# json dumps all returns index instead of attribute

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to grab data from my mysql database.

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute(SELECT id FROM users)

mysql.connection.commit()
data = cur.fetchall()
return jsonify({"result": data})
```

Right now my code returns: {result: [[1]]} However, I want my result to show something like this: {result: {id: 1}} the id is the attribute inside the SQL table and 1 is the value

I am wondering if theres is a easy way to retrieving the attribute manually from the SQL database or if I have to add manually something like this `data = {'id': data[0][0]}` before the return line.

Comment: hi please https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What type of object is `cur`? What DB connection library is it from?

Comment: @xdhmoore i edited the post. It is from flask_mysqldb

Comment: Can you show an example of the contents of the database, the exact corresponding result you get, and the exact corresponding result you want? Without any context, I can't understand how the example `"[[id, "1"]]"` is supposed to be related to what's in your database or to `"[[0, "test"]]"`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I updated the post. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: It looks like there may be a `cur.column_names` method or field? Maybe that could be combined with your `data` object to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor object has [`description`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-description.html) property, which gives you information about columns in a result set. It's a list of tuples, the first element being the column name.

So you could do this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM users")
column_names = [col[0] for col in cur.description]
data = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
return jsonify({"result": data})
```

Here `data` is a list of dictionaries with the format `{'column_name': value}`.